# layout behavior not as expected in case of different device

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my output form different device configuration [Layout Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgKG.jpg)

I need static layout.

My layout is not behaving like as expected. it shows different in different device. without scroll fix to screen.
Using Constraint Layout
this is my layout code.

**layout.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewOnboarding"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight = "1.0"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:background="@drawable/onboarding_pantry"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          android:contentDescription="@string/title_splash" />


   <TextView
          android:id="@+id/headerText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
          android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
          android:text="@string/text_start_cooking"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewOnboarding"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/headerTextDetail"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingStart="@dimen/_50sdp"
          android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_50sdp"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
          android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:lines="2"
          android:textColor="@color/main_text_color_light"
          android:text="@string/text_start_cooking_detail"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerText"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_40sdp"
          android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
          android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/default_round_button"
          android:text="@string/action_text_getStarted"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerTextDetail"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also I don't want to add scroll in layout.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your views are not in bottom constraints. this code is verified on different devices.
add **app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf** constrains to each of your views.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewOnboarding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/headerText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Start Cooking"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/headerTextDetail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewOnboarding" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerTextDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingEnd="50dp"
    android:text="let's join our community to cook better food!"
    android:textColor="#FF000000"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/getStartedText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Get Started"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerTextDetail" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because image view has no bottom constraints. To fix this add only bottom constraints to `getStartedText` and app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf for all above items so that they are contraint vertically starting from bottom. And for image view add `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/headerText"` so that all the free space above headerText and top of parent is used by image view.

With below constraints it will work fine on all screen sizes.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewOnboarding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "1.0"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/headerText"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="text_start_cooking"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/headerTextDetail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headerTextDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="text_start_cooking_detail"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/getStartedText"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="action_text_getStarted"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```